# RVIZ will not execute

Tags: lidar, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a LiDar taken from the Neato XV-11 vacuum cleaner on ROS nad amd using RVIZ to visualize the data coming from the sensor. However, I ran into the problem that RVIZ was not receiving and MAP data to display. I consulted the site and As per the video tutorial under map, I found that I did not have any topics being displayed. I tried to enter the topic manually but not RVIZ will not initialize and I am receiving the following error.

*[ERROR] [1338754771.604753719]: Caught exception while loading: Character [ ] at element [3] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [map (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.*

Kindly suggest what when wrong and what can be done regarding the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35554/rviz-will-not-execute/) by [rzv0004](https://answers.ros.org/users/2525/rzv0004/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to me you placed a space in *map (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)* which is not valid.

Remove that space in *~/.rviz/display_config* or *~/.rviz/config* and start rviz.

Previously:

- http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/RVIZ-Graph-Resource-Name-Problem-td1678927.html
- http://answers.ros.org/question/11321/caught-exception-while-loading-character-/

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0